# UIViewController maintains state after being nilled

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, uiviewcontroller, automatic-ref-counting

In my app, I made a `BookViewController` class that displays and animates the pages of a book and a `MainMenuViewController` class that displays a set of books the user can read.

In the latter class, when the user taps on one of the books, a function is called that should create a completely new instance of `BookViewController`, but for some reason the instance maintains its state  (i.e. it resumes from the page the user left off).

How can this be if I set it to nil? What am I missing here? (Note that I'm using ARC).

**MainMenuViewController.m**

```
@interface MainMenuViewController ()
@property (strong) BookViewController *bookViewController;
@end

@implementation MainMenuViewController
@synthesize bookViewController;

-(void)bookTapped:(UIButton *)sender{

    NSString *bookTitle;

    if(sender == book1button) bookTitle = @"book1";
    else if(sender == book2button) bookTitle = @"book2";

    bookViewController = nil;

    bookViewController = [[BookViewController alloc] initWithBookTitle:bookTitle];
    [self presentViewController:bookViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

**BookViewController.h**

```
@interface BookViewController : UIViewController
-(id)initWithBookTitle:(NSString *)bookTitle;
@end
```

**BookViewController.m**

```
@implementation BookViewController
-(id)initWithBookTitle:(NSString *)theBookTitle{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        bookTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", theBookTitle];
        [self setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
        NSLog(@"init a BookViewController with bookTitle: %@", bookTitle);
    }
    return self;
}
```

**edit 1:** 
Every time a book is tapped, `bookTapped:` is called, and thee console always prints:

`2012-08-31 16:29:51.750 AppName[25713:c07] init a BookViewController with bookTitle: book1`

So if a new instance of `BookViewController` is being created, how come it seems to be returning the old one?

**edit 2:**
I inserted  `NSLog(@"bookViewController %@",bookViewController);`  just before the line `[self presentViewController:bookViewController`. The console output is:

```
2012-08-31 16:37:41.426 Henry[25784:c07] bookViewController <BookViewController: 0x6a21540>
2012-08-31 16:38:23.321 Henry[25784:c07] bookViewController <BookViewController: 0xe425540>
2012-08-31 16:38:53.393 Henry[25784:c07] bookViewController <BookViewController: 0x6839330>
```

Comment: It would be interesting to see what happens in some `BookViewController` methods such as `initWithBookTitle:` or `viewDidLoad:` or `viewWillAppear:`/`viewDidAppear:`.

Comment: I edited my question to include the code for `initWithBookTitle:`... BookViewController's `viewDidLoad` just sets up the view layout...

Comment: I see you have some potentially useful logging in there. Can you add your log?

Comment: Please add

NSLog(@"bookViewController %@",bookViewController); before

 [self presentViewController:bookViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

And also log the theBookTitle value.

Comment: Maybe you linked the two buttons to same outlet?

Comment: @StevenFisher I edited the question to include the logs.

Comment: @Eric, please include my logs as well, the problem might be at a higher level.

Comment: You say your symptom is that "it resumes from the page the user left off", but you don't show any code on how you're displaying that book -- it seems like the problem lies there, unless you're not even getting the right title logged.  Are you getting the right title in the log you posted?

Comment: @Resh32 I edited the question to include the logs you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks @Eric, please log the bookTitle value, and check that your buttons are correctly linked

Comment: So, it's clearly not returning the old controller (by those addresses) but, seemingly, displaying the same book in the new controller.

Comment: @PhillipMills exactly... Why would it do that?

Comment: @rdelmar yes I am getting the right title... The buttons are correctly linked. The setup code is too long and boring to be pasted here. Besides it doesn't really make a difference, the instance returned is indeed new.

Comment: You say, "I am getting the right title", but you also say that the console always shows "bookTitle: book1".  These statements don't go together.  :)

Comment: @Eric, to isolate your problem, try to create a new local instance each time, like: BookViewController* tempBookViewController = [[BookViewController alloc] initWithBookTitle:@"book1"]

Comment: and put a randomly generated book. Something like bookTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"book%d",arc4random()%2];

Comment: @Eric, is MainMenuViewController extending another class than UIViewController? Do you have categories or anything else that might interfere with presentViewController?

Comment: @Eric, I think that it is self.bookTitle instead of bookTitle that is creating the problem.

Comment: There's something a little bit crazy here... I followed @Resh32's suggestion and did: `BookViewController *tempBookViewController = [[BookViewController alloc] initWithBookTitle:@"book1"]` and it's presenting the old view controller!

Comment: @Eric, what do you call the old viewcontroller?

Comment: @Resh32: No, MainMenuViewController is only extending UIViewController.

Comment: Anyway, I'm sure that you'll quickly figure it out and that it will look obvious when you figure.

Comment: @Eric, also try the self.bookName instead of bookName, I really don't know what append when you set the ivar during the init call. Is bookName a property BTW?

Comment: You didn't respond to one of the comments above about always getting "bookTitle: book1" in the console, yet you say you get the correct title in your log.  Which is it? Do you get "bookTitle: book2" in the console if you click on book2button or not?

Comment: @rdelmar: yes, the console prints the right book title.

Comment: Then, the problem doesn't appear to be what you said in your title -- you're getting the right title and the log shows new instances of your BookViewController.  I think the problem is in the "long and boring" part of the code that you didn't post. You should put a log in the place where you actually present the book to make sure it's getting called when you create a new book controller.

Comment: @Eric, did you solve this? We are all wondering what it could be...

Comment: #import "BookViewController.h"
    int currentPage = 0;
    UIButton *homeButton;
    UIButton *infoButton;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables are declared outside of the @implementation of the class (you are declaring global variables).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are using the ivars instead of the properties. Please replace `bookViewController` with `self.bookViewController`.

Try:

```
if(self){
        self.bookTitle
```

Comment: I don't see how that would make a difference with ARC. Can you explain your thinking?

Comment: I tried replacing `bookViewController` with `self.bookViewController` and the problem was still there...

Comment: @Steven, that was just a quick thought when I saw this problem it reminded me of similar problems with ivars instead of properties. I agree that ARC will therefore make no difference between ivar and property call in this case.

Comment: @Steven, what do you think about the ivar assignment during the init method call?

Comment: I think that's the recommendation, actually. But I would've either used automatic synthesis or `@synthesized bookTitle = _bookTitle` to avoid potential confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The variables that were maintaing their state in the new instance were declared thus:

```
#import "BookViewController.h"

int currentPage = 0;

@implementation BookViewController

-(id)initWithBookTitle:(NSString *)theBookTitle{
...
```

So I managed to fix the issue by initialising the variables in the init method:

```
-(id)initWithBookTitle:(NSString *)theBookTitle{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        currentPage = 0; //added this line
        bookTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", theBookTitle];
        [self setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];

         NSLog(@"init a BookViewController with bookTitle: %@", bookTitle);
    }
    return self;
}
```

But this doesn't solve the underlying problem, which is that doing this:

```
bookViewController = [[BookViewController alloc] initWithBookTitle:bookTitle];
[self presentViewController:bookViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

still presents a bookViewController with the old value for `currentPage`! This might be because I'm not declaring it as a property, nor initialising it in the `init` method... Any thoughts?

Comment: Your variables are declared outside of the @implementation of the class (you are declaring global variables).